# InputMismatchException in backtracking algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, backtracking

I`m trying to find how man times a given name is repeated in a matrix but i have this InputMismatchException that i can not fix. I suppose that the problem is from the scanner variable but i can understand what is the problem.

```
private static char[][] words= { { 'n', 'i', 'k', 'i' }, { 'e', 'v', 'n', 'h', }, { 'i', 'n', 'a', 'v', },
        { 'm', 'v', 'v', 'n', }, { 'q', 'r', 'i', 't', } };

private static void findName(int row, int col, String direction) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter name.");

    String name = input.nextLine();

    StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder();
    int counter = 0;

    if ((col < 0) || (row < 0) || (col >= words[0].length) || (row >= words.length)) {
        // We are out of the labyrinth
        return;
    }

    if (words[row][col] != ' ') {
        // The current cell is not free
        return;
    } else {
        word = word.append(lab[row][col]);
    }

    // Check if we have found the exit

    if (word.equals(name)) {
        counter++;
        System.out.printf("Name - {%s} found %s times%n", name, counter);
        word = null;
    }

    // Mark the current cell as visited
    words[row][col] = 's';
    // Invoke recursion the explore all possible directions
    findName(row, col - 1, "L"); // left
    System.out.printf("L");
    findName(row - 1, col, "U"); // up
    System.out.printf("U");
    findName(row, col + 1, "R"); // right
    System.out.printf("R");
    findName(row + 1, col, "D"); // down
    System.out.printf("D");
    // Mark back the current cell as free
    words[row][col] = ' ';
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    findName(0, 0, "R");
}
```

Comment: Why is `name` an `int`?

Comment: Also struggling with you naming ... what is "lab" supposed to mean? I would advise you to give the things names that resemble what they are ... makes reading and understanding your source code much easier ...

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll I`ve fix my code but now when i enter some name in console the program stops.

Answer (score 0):

You say

```
System.out.println("Enter name.");

int name = input.nextInt();
```

I assume you want the name to be a `String` not an `int`.

So you should replace it with

```
String name = input.nextLine();
```

This will also fix your InputMismatchError which probably occurs when you later try and compare `word` with `name`. Although you might have to call `toString()` on your `StringBuilder word` before you can compare it to your `String name`.